# LINQ to SQL Insert Failing because of Join

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql, join

I've got two tables in my database `Users` and `HealthMonitor`.  In the `HealthMonitor` table I have a `UserID` field that is mapped to the `ID` field in the `Users` table.

Pretty straight forward so far...

I left the `UserID` field in the `HealthMonitor` table as "Nullable" so that I can have the system insert a NULL value into the table if there is no current User logged in... IE: if an error is thrown to a non authenticated user.

The problem is that the insert fails when I'm trying to insert NULL into that `UserID` field.

*FYI: removing the relationship also removes the problem, however I know it's probably not the best way to accomplish the task*

## <strike>EDIT:</strike>

After re applying the relationship and ensuring that `UserID` was nullable, it appears to work now... however the value is inserted as `0` not `null`

```
    Public Sub AddException(ByVal ex As Exception, Optional ByVal notes As String = Nothing) Implements IHealthMonitorService.AddException
        Dim exception As HealthMonitor = New HealthMonitor
        Dim userID As Integer = Nothing
        If HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated Then userID = Authentication.CustomAuthentication.RetrieveAuthUser.ID

        Dim DataConverter As Utilities.DataConverters = New Utilities.DataConverters
        Dim InformationHelper As Utilities.InformationHelper = New Utilities.InformationHelper

        With exception
            .DateTime = DateTime.Now
            .Exception = ex.ToString
            .Message = ex.Message
            .Notes = notes
            .ShortMessage = If(ex.Message.Length > 50, ex.Message.Substring(0, 50), ex.Message)
            .Source = ex.Source
            .StackTrace = ex.StackTrace
            .Url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString()
            .UserID = userID
            .UserIP = DataConverter.IPAddressToNumber(InformationHelper.GetUserIP)
            .UserOS = InformationHelper.GetUserOS()
            .UserBrowser = InformationHelper.GetUserBrowser()
        End With

        _HealthMonitorRepository.AddException(exception)
    End Sub
```

Am I missing something here? can it be inserted as `NULL`

## EDIT:

OK, So I lied a little.  I'm still getting the error

```
    Public Sub AddException(ByVal exception As HealthMonitor) Implements IHealthMonitorRepository.AddException
        dc.HealthMonitors.InsertOnSubmit(exception)
        dc.SubmitChanges()  ''# ERROR HERE
    End Sub
```

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_un_HealthMonitor_un_Users". The conflict occurred in database "UrbanNow", table "dbo.un_Users", column 'ID'.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Here's the Table

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[un_HealthMonitor]    Script Date: 07/24/2010 10:48:39 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[un_HealthMonitor](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserID] [int] NULL,
    [Exception] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [Url] [nvarchar](2048) NULL,
    [Source] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [ShortMessage] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Message] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [StackTrace] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [UserIP] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [UserBrowser] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [UserOS] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [UserIsMoblie] [bit] NULL,
    [DateTime] [datetime2](0) NULL,
    [Notes] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_un_HealthMonitor] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[un_HealthMonitor]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_un_HealthMonitor_un_Users] FOREIGN KEY([UserID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[un_Users] ([ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[un_HealthMonitor] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_un_HealthMonitor_un_Users]
GO
```

Comment: Instead of having the field be Nullable, how about a trigger to populate it with a known value ('N/A' or 0 or something equivalent).

Comment: trigger - yuck. If that's the case, I can submit a "0" value through LINQ but it still fails because there is no associated "0" record in the Users table

Comment: @JNK, Null is the correct value when there's nothing on the other end of the relationship. It would be a shame to resort to a workaround like that. @rockinthesixstring, are you using VS? Have you checked in your .dbml designer that the property is marked Nullable? Maybe it just got imported incorrectly.

Comment: I have not checked in the designer.  I'll look right away.

Comment: It seems as though when I rebuilt it and checked to ensure that UserID was Nullable, it works now.  I've edited my question though because the value is going in as "0" and not "NULL"

Comment: Edited Again, I lack of errors was because I did it wrong.  I'm obviously STILL doing it wrong, but what I'm looking for is to do it RIGHT.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: A foreign key shouldn't keep you from inserting NULL into a nullable field, so I can only guess you're inserting another value. Probably 0, judging from the stricken edits. I'm not experienced in the VB type system, but I'd say it has to do with that line `Dim userID As Integer = Nothing`. Maybe you want `System.DBNull.Value` instead of `Nothing`?

Comment: That's pretty much the answer.  See my answer below for my solution.

Answer (score 0):

NAILED IT!!!

So basically in my Service layer I had...

```
    Public Sub AddException(ByVal ex As Exception, Optional ByVal notes As String = Nothing) Implements IHealthMonitorService.AddException
        Dim exception As HealthMonitor = New HealthMonitor
        Dim userID As Integer = Nothing
        If HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated Then userID = Authentication.CustomAuthentication.RetrieveAuthUser.ID

        Dim DataConverter As Utilities.DataConverters = New Utilities.DataConverters
        Dim InformationHelper As Utilities.InformationHelper = New Utilities.InformationHelper

        With exception
            .DateTime = DateTime.Now
            .Exception = ex.ToString
            .Message = ex.Message
            .Notes = notes
            .ShortMessage = If(ex.Message.Length > 50, ex.Message.Substring(0, 50), ex.Message)
            .Source = ex.Source
            .StackTrace = ex.StackTrace
            .Url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString()
            .UserID = userID
            .UserIP = DataConverter.IPAddressToNumber(InformationHelper.GetUserIP)
            .UserOS = InformationHelper.GetUserOS()
            .UserBrowser = InformationHelper.GetUserBrowser()
        End With

        _HealthMonitorRepository.AddException(exception)
    End Sub
```

The problem with this is that when I send `userID` to the exception object, It was sending `0` (ZERO) to the database.  here's the solution

```
        Dim userID As Integer? = Nothing ''# (?) makes the integer nullable.
```

Answer (score -1):

To ensure you have a User and therefor don't violate the foreign key, could you do something like:

```
`Public Sub AddException(ByVal exception As HealthMonitor) Implements IHealthMonitorRepository.AddException
    ' take what you need from exception to Create a User
    User user = new User{Populate properties here}
    dc.Users.InsertOnSubmit(user)   
    dc.HealthMonitors.InsertOnSubmit(exception)
    dc.SubmitChanges()  ''# ERROR HERE
End Sub'
```

and that way you create the user if you need it.

Or you could do an existence check for the user.

Comment: I don't want to create a user for an anonymous visitor to the website, that's just ludicrous.  I found my answer, take a look. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325508/linq-to-sql-insert-failing-because-of-join/3326053#3326053